# I'm getting a runtime error when building a reactive form

Tags: dart, angular-reactive-forms, angular-dart

This runtime error happens when trying to build a reactive Angular form in Dart with dartdevc:

```
Type 'List<Type>' is not a subtype of expected type 'num'.
```

The error is happening in my `buildForm()` function.

```
  ControlGroup buildForm()
  {
    return FormBuilder.controlGroup(
      {
        // Error happens on the next statement 
        'fee': Control<num>([null, PositiveNumValidator]),
        'fi':  Control<num>([null, PositiveNumValidator]),
        'fo':  Control<num>([null, PositiveNumValidator]),
        'fum': Control<num>([null, PositiveNumValidator])
      });
  }
```

If I remove `<num>` in the Control configuration, the error changes to:

```
Type 'List<Type>' is not a subtype of expected type 'String'.
```

The whole context of the function is:

```
class MyForm implements OnInit
{
  ControlGroup form;
  ...

  ControlGroup buildForm()
  {...}

  @override
  ngOnInit()
  form = buildForm();
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo - Should be ngOnInit(){form = buildForm()}

Answer (score 2):

```
'fee': Control<num>([null, PositiveNumValidator]),
```

should be

```
'fee': Control<num>([null, PositiveNumValidator().validate]),
```

or

```
'fee': [null, PositiveNumValidator().validate],
```

See also

- https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_forms/angular_forms/FormBuilder-class
- https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_forms/angular_forms/Validators/required
- https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_components/angular_components/PositiveNumValidator/validate

Comment: Thanks very much. I missed that the Configuration requires a ValidatorFn, not a Validator.